# WinForms: PictureBox initialization issue

Tags: c#, image, draw, picturebox

If I put PictureBox initialization into form's constructor or `form.Load` / `form.Shown` handler nothing is drawn on PictureBox. If initialization is being made just before drawing, graphics appears.

Why this code draws an array on PictureBox:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Bitmap drawArea;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void drawArray(int[] arr, PictureBox box)
    {
        //=========== Attention to this code ================
        drawArea = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Size.Width, pictureBox1.Size.Height);
        pictureBox1.Image = drawArea;
        //===================================================
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(drawArea))
        {
            Pen mypen = new Pen(Brushes.Black);
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                g.DrawLine(mypen, i*2, drawArea.Height,
                   i*2, drawArea.Height - arr[i]);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] ar1 = randomArray(20, 1, 20);
        drawArray(ar1, pictureBox1);
    }
}
```

but this code doesn't?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Bitmap drawArea;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //=========== Attention to this code ================
        //Breakpoint here: pictureBox1.Size.Width==409, pictureBox1.Size.Height==205
        drawArea = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Size.Width, pictureBox1.Size.Height);
        pictureBox1.Image = drawArea;
        //===================================================
    }

    private void drawArray(int[] arr, PictureBox box)
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(drawArea))
        {
            Pen mypen = new Pen(Brushes.Black);
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                g.DrawLine(mypen, i*2, drawArea.Height,
                  i*2, drawArea.Height - arr[i]);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] ar1 = randomArray(20, 1, 20);
        drawArray(ar1, pictureBox1);
    }
}
```

It does not even work if I make a second button and put the initialization code in its handler (and of course click second button before clicking the first).

No exception is thrown.

Comment: Are you sure that if you run the code from the Form Load event, instead of from the constructor, it does not work either?

Comment: @varocarbas: yes, I've checked it again and it didn't work.

Comment: Not working from the constructor (even trigerring an error) makes kind of sense as far as the given control (pictureBox1) hasn't still be initialised; that's why, it is always better to affect controls' properties from the the Load Event method. But other than that, I cannot come up with a valid reason (other than: there is something in your code making it behave weirdly). For example: are you affecting the PictureBox1 in any way between the Load event until the moment when the button is clicked?

Comment: @varocarbas: it does not fire any exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure...just Invalidate() the PictureBox in drawArray() so it refreshes itself:

```
    private void drawArray(int[] arr, PictureBox box)
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(drawArea))
        {
            Pen mypen = new Pen(Brushes.Black);
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                g.DrawLine(mypen, i * 2, drawArea.Height,
                  i * 2, drawArea.Height - arr[i]);
        }
        box.Invalidate();
    }
```

*Why were you passing the PictureBox anyways, if you weren't using it?

Comment: `box.Invalidate()` did the job! Q: `... if you weren't using it?` A: It is not a complete code here.